# Can not add account as role admin in Apple developer

Tags: ios

I try to add new account as role admin, I already use an account with role **Account Holder** but when dialog add admin I can't check to option **Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles** in **Developer Resources** sector and when I hit **Invite** it show error like image below.
[image: add admin]

Does anybody know this error, please help me? I research from google but no luck.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using an Individual Account, aren't you?. 
If that, please check on here.

> Note: If you’re enrolled as an individual and add users in App Store Connect, users receive access only to your content in App Store Connect and are not considered part of your team in the Apple Developer Program.

https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

Comment: Yes, it is an individual account, I didn't know that. Thanks